# Showing and hiding divs if checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have several checkboxes in different places on the page. When one of those checkboxes is selected then the div underneath it should disappear signaling that they do not wish to upload any files.

I can get this to work with a checkbox, but my issue comes when there are many of them since I am calling the same class to make this work because I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible. Mainly so I don't have to write a separate function for each checkbox.

```
<div class="className">
    <p class="mailCheck "><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox-select" id="questionnaire-check" <span>I dont wish to upload files at this time.</span></p>

    <div class="hideDiv hideUpload">
        <p>Upload box I wish to hide.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery I have been playing with.

I have tried a few things here. First, I had just the if statement which worked when the user refreshed and then I had the click function. But neither seemed to work on individual checkboxes, just the group as whole.

```
if($('.mailCheck input:checked').length == 1){
        $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').hide();
    }else {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').show();
    }

    $('.mailCheck input').on('click', function(){
        if($('.mailCheck input:checked').length == 1){
            $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').slideUp();
        }else {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').slideDown();
        }
    });
```

So then I tried to put the above code in a `.each` function, but that just seemed to mess up how the click function was supposed to work.

```
$('.mailCheck input').each(function() {

});
```

So I tried to take the click function out of the each function, but that didn't seem to help either. I'm probably making this way more complex than needed. Any help would be appreciated!

A jsFiddle to try and visualize what I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/gDp8z/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onchange` event, not `onclick`, then check for specific checkbox:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDp8z/10/)

```
$('.mailCheck input').on('change', function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').slideUp();
        }else {
            $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').slideDown();
        }
    }).change();
```

Or using `slideToggle()`:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDp8z/9/)

```
$('.mailCheck input').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.hideUpload').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This seems to work in the fiddle, but in my actual code it does not seem to work. The first checkbox works fine, but then when you get to the second one the upload box is already gone and it tries to hide it even though it's not there.

Comment: You need to remove click handler from each loop, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gDp8z/11

Comment: I did do that. But I somehow need that if statement if it's already checked on refresh then the div needs to be hidden and if it's unchecked then it needs to show. Because the toggle does not check if it is already checked or not.

Comment: I did, it still does not work completely because if you refresh the page and it's checked and you check it then the input hides and does not show.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know you could do a conditional that way.